# How to get document size before downloading that

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I want to download a document which i do it by following code

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:500];

   [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]; 


NSData *returnData =[[NSURL alloc]init];
    returnData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

and depending on the data downloaded i want to show progress bar , is there any way how i can do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your delegate of `NSURLConnection` implement method `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response`. In this method you can call

```
long long expLength = [response expectedContentLength];
```

In `expLength` you will have expected document size.

But be caution:

> Some protocol implementations report the content length as part of the
>   response, but not all protocols guarantee to deliver that amount of
>   data. Clients should be prepared to deal with more or less data.

Answer (score 1):

The NSURLConnection calls its delegate with

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
```

Well, we need to look inside the NSURLResponse, to find the expectedContentLength

```
- (long long)expectedContentLength   

Return Value The receiver’s expected content length,
or NSURLResponseUnknownLength if the length can’t be determined.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in either ways using Synchronous/Asynchronous call. For Asynchronous there delegate methods are there which you need to implement in your class and for Synchronous you can call it within your method scope.